# Default values in \newcommand & renewing \maketitle

Tags: titles, documentclass-writing

I am working on customizing a thesis document class according to my needs.
I am trying to renew the `\maketitle` command to modify my title page, and I am facing two problems:

1. I wish to define a newcommand for the logo in the title page. If there is no user-defined parameter, a default value called "logo.pdf" should be passed to the `\includegraphics` command to load the default logo.

   ```
   \newcommand{\logo}[1][logo.pdf]{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{#1}}
   ```

   Is this correct?
2. There seems to be some problem with my class file, as I keep getting the `Undefined control sequence in \maketitle` error. Below is my document class:

**`mythesis.cls`:**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[2013/07/25 v1.0 My thesis class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}

\RequirePackage{graphicx} % needed for logo and pictures

\newcommand{\logo}[1][logo.pdf]{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{#1}}
\newcommand{\college}[1][My School]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[1][My degree]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\university}[1][My university]{{#1}}

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse
       \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
       \fi}%
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn
       \else\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
        {\large \vspace*{10mm} {\@logo \par} \vspace*{15mm}}
        {{\Large \bf \@author} \par}
        {\large \vspace*{1ex} {{\@college} \par}
        {\large \@university \par}
        {\Large \it {\@degree} \par}
        \vspace*{2ex}
        {\today}}
    \end{center}
\null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}
}
\makeatother
```

**`thesis.tex`:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mythesis}

\begin{document}
\title{My research}
\author{My name}
\logo{logo_new.pdf}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.
P.S.: I am a newbie, especially in document class creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both your problems are addressed in the below provided edited class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[2013/07/25 v1.0 My thesis class]
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}

\RequirePackage{graphicx} % needed for logo and pictures

\let\@college\@empty
\let\@degree\@empty
\let\@university\@empty
\def\@logo{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{logo.pdf}}
\newcommand{\logo}[1]{\gdef\@logo{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\college}[1][My School]{\gdef\@college{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[1][My degree]{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\newcommand{\university}[1][My university]{\gdef\@university{#1}}

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse
       \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
       \fi}%
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn
       \else\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}

\renewcommand\maketitle{
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bfseries\@title\par}
        {\vspace*{10mm}\par\@logo\par\vspace*{15mm}}
        {\Large\bfseries\@author\par}
        {\ifx\@college\@empty\else\large\vspace*{1ex}\par\@college\par\fi}
        {\ifx\@university\@empty\else\large\@university\par\fi}
        {\ifx\@degree\@empty\else\Large\itshape\@degree\par\fi}
        \vspace*{2ex}
        {\today}
    \end{center}
\null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}
}
\endinput
```

Some points:

1. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is not required in class and style files. If you give one, then it is not a problem.
2. See `\@logo` defined above. It will be taken as default if you did not provided `\logo`  command in your TeX file, otherwise `\logo` command will redefine `\@logo` with the new file you had given in the TeX file.
3. Commands like `\@logo`, `\@college`, `\@degree`, `\@university` etc were not defined inside `\maketitle` which were causing the error. I have added those in their respective macros.
4. Commands such as `\it`, `\bf`, `\sl` etc are now obsolete and we need to use `\itshape`, `\bfseries`, `\slshape` etc.

Otherwise, its a great way to start with!

Comment: Thanks! It fixed all my errors. Just a few questions: (1) why do you make use of \gdef? (2) can I make use of \newcommand instead of \def? Is it just a personal choice or is there a reason why you used it?

Comment: @PradeepKumar: `\gdef` is `\global\def`. It overrides the `\def`. I personally used `\def` rather than `\newcommand`, which is more convenient for me. The main logic is, define a default value for logo inside `\@logo` and if you have your own logo provided by `\logo` command in TeX, make it a global value to `\@logo` and override the default value.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, but there might be a better way. Why? Well, you create `\logo[<logo>]` to have an optional argument but you would never call `\logo` *without* an argument so that it would take the default. That is, it should take the default of `logo.pdf` by default, without doing anything else. Perhaps using

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\logo}[1]{\def\@logoname{#1}}\logo{logo.pdf}
   \def\@logo{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{\@logoname}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   would help. This creates `\logo{<logo>}` which stores it's argument in `\@logoname`. Then immediately sets the default to `logo.pdf`, and subsequently defines `\@logo` to insert `\@logoname` (whatever it may be).
2. Similar to the above, you need to define the way the unknown macros `\@college`, `\@university` and `\@degree` function. Perhaps you can do something similar for these:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\college}[1]{\def\@collegename{#1}}\college{My college}
   \def\@college{\@collegename}
   \newcommand{\university}[1]{\def\@universityname{#1}}\university{My university}
   \def\@university{\@universityname}
   \newcommand{\degree}[1]{\def\@degreename{#1}}\degree{My degree}
   \def\@degree{\@degreename}
   \makeatother
   ```

   In this instance, the use of `\@college` as an alias `\@collegename` is a bit superfluous, so you could use `\@collegename` directly in your `\maketitle` construction. Your choice.